# Gitlab permissions view wiki, Issues but not source?

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to have a user level that can view project wikis and file issues but not view the code stored in the project?

I'd like to have some people being able to view the code and a larger audience that can just read the wiki and track issues.

Doesn't look like there is an access level between can't see a project and have access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that's possible at the moment.

There's a table of permissions here: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/permissions/permissions.html

The least priviliged group is `Guest` and even they have access to the source code.